# Oracle SQL does not work for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm an Oracle DBA and not familiar with MS Access. Would you please help me to convert the following SQL to make it work for MS Access? MILLION THANKS!

```
select
   (case 
       when subject like '%requires your attention%' 
         then 'Project Leader: ' + LEFT(CC, case when CHARINDEX(';',cc)=0 then LEN(cc) else CHARINDEX(';',cc)-1 end)

       when subject like '%Assigned or Changed%'  
         then 'Project assigned DBA: ' + LEFT(CC, case when CHARINDEX(';',cc)=0 then LEN(cc) else CHARINDEX(';',cc)-1 end) 

       when subject like '%Off Hold%' 
         then 'Project Leader: ' + LEFT(CC, case when CHARINDEX(';',cc)=0 then LEN(cc) else CHARINDEX(';',cc)-1 end)

       when subject like '%On Hold%' 
         then 'Project Leader: ' + LEFT(CC, case when CHARINDEX(';',cc)=0 then LEN(cc) else CHARINDEX(';',cc)-1 end)

       else 'project leader or assigneed is not specified'

   end) as project_assignee
from 
   project
```

Comment: Replace `Case` statements with [IIF()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php) and `CHARINDEX` with [Instr()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/instr.php) functions. Alternatively, connect Oracle via ODBC and retain SQL in a [pass-though query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/303968).

Comment: Your original syntax is not Oracle.  It is SQL Server.  You should update the question appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

First, your syntax is not Oracle, it looks like SQL Server.

I think the following (modulo typos) should work in MS Access:

```
select iif(subject like '*requires your attention*',
           'Project Leader: ' & iif(cc NOT LIKE '*;*', CC, LEFT(cc, INSTR(cc, ';') - 1))
           iif(subject like '*Assigned or Changed*',
               'Project assigned DBA: ' & iif(cc NOT LIKE '*;*', CC, LEFT(cc, INSTR(cc, ';') - 1))
               iif(subject like '*Off Hold*',
                   'Project Leader: ' & iif(cc NOT LIKE '*;*', CC, LEFT(cc, INSTR(cc, ';') - 1))
                   iif(subject like '*On Hold*',
                       'Project Leader: ' & iif(cc NOT LIKE '*;*', CC, LEFT(cc, INSTR(cc, ';') - 1)),
                       'project leader or assigneed is not specified'
                      )
                  )
              )
          ) as project_assignee
from project;
```

Changes:

- MS Access doesn't support `CASE`, use nested `iif()` instead.
- `like` in MS Access uses different wildcards, so `*` instead of `%`.
- There is no `CHARINDEX()`.  Instead, `INSTR()`.
- String concatenation is `&`, rather than `+`.

Comment: The [Switch() function](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) is often a better substitute than nested IIf() functions when converting a `CASE` construct..

Comment: `IIF` is a shining example of the bastard dialect known as MS Access SQL.  If Microsoft was going to include similar functionality, why rename it?  I have flashbacks every time I see it.